# Debugging application via chrome ARC Welder

Tags: android, debugging, adb

is it possible to debug application from Android IDE(AndroidStudio, eclipse, etc) directly and receive application log?

is it need another extension for IDEs or not?

when I run `ARC Welder` and test it , it's correct :

[image]

but when I run application , not shown me `ARC Welder` for choosing!

[image]

Too , before I saw this : https://github.com/vladikoff/chromeos-apk/blob/master/archon.md and not helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it's possible to debug application from Android IDE(Like android
>   studion, eclipse or...) directly and receive application log?

Until now with ***[Arc Welder (beta)](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/getstarted_arc)*** that´s not possible

Answer (score 1):

currently i'm working on ionicframework project. i use arc welder to debug my app, well i don't know if such plugin is available. for now i manually add the app to arc welder before start to debug it.

you can directly debug from chrome if you want, use chrome://inspect then choose app you will see your app there choose inpect

hope this help you mate

Comment: can you see the app that is runing on ARC on the chrome://inspect page? without a mobile phone, just using ARC...?